# after ajax success I call showProducts()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been following a CRUD tutorial, located here https://www.codeofaninja.com/2015/06/php-crud-with-ajax-and-oop.html.
I can create update and delete, but when ajax success fires I get an error:

> showProducts() not defined

Thus the products list does not refresh. I don't understand how `showProducts()` can be found without some type of reference to it. I know `showProducts()` works because it is called on `$(document).ready(function()`

```
{
 // show list of product on first load
    showProducts(); 
}); 
 works fine.

    // send delete request to api / remote server
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/api/product/delete.php",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify({ id: product_id }),
        success : function(result) {

            // re-load list of products
            showProducts();
        },
        error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
            console.log(xhr, resp, text);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: is your ajax and showProducts function are in the same context?

Comment: how is `showProducts()` getting defined? are you calling it before it's getting define? easy way to find out call it before you AJAX request to make sure is not an issue of loosing scope

Comment: read-products.js is where showProducts() is defined. read-products.js lives in index.php<script>

Comment: read-products.js is where showProducts() is defined. read-products.js lives in index.php<script> @Roljhon @ santi6291 Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing teh code from 6.3:

```
// function to show list of products
function showProducts(){

}
```

But, later on (in 11.4) they change it to:

```
// function to show list of products
function showProducts(){

    // get list of products from the API
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/api/product/read.php", function(data){

        // html for listing products
        readProductsTemplate(data, "");

        // chage page title
        changePageTitle("Read Products");

    });
}
```

Comment: thanks 6.3 was replaced by 11.4 
showProducts() lives in read-products.js which is located in index.php
#kakashi senpai is correct if I make a copy of the showProducts() function and paste it before the .ajax code it works fine, but I am duplicating code in 4 different locations. there has to be a way to give the path to the function showProducts()

Answer (score 0):

because your `showProducts()` function not defined

simply create a one before your ( $ajax call ) and Add some data in to it , example :

```
// function to show list of products
function showProducts(){
   // you can change those contents and add whatever you like. 
   $(document).ready(function() {  
       $("#emptydiv").html("<body> Add your prodects here </body>");
    });

 }
```

the html div you want to put your data in :

```
<div id="emptydiv"> </div>
```

> what we add here inside (**showProducts** function) is  *just example* . you can add what ever you want (**depend** on if you want to follow the tutorial completely or you want to add your Owen style and content ) .

- and in the **tutorial link you mention** they add those content :

  ```
  // function to show list of products
  function showProducts(){

    // get list of products from the API
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/api/product/read.php", function(data){

      // html for listing products
      readProductsTemplate(data, "");

     // chage page title
     changePageTitle("Read Products");

    });
  }
  ```

Comment: sure if I put the function ahead of the .ajax code, it worsk fine. Now I have to copy the exact code and paste it into the following files
create-products.js, edit-products.js, delete.js this looks like i am duplicating code in 3 different locations. 

I thought the code required a path to the function showProducts() 
like 'read-products.js -> showProducts();'